React Native app not building due to mismatch between js and native codes and other potential issues
im stuck during 1 week now to simply build my react native app for my first project in a company, basically for android it said it has a mismatch between react native and native code versions, 0.61.3 and 0.64.4 basically, it said I could rebuild the native code to update it, i tried to run npx react-native run-ios and run-android but none of them worked because they didnt recognized a command I had to install, it was pod, i should do pod install, but to do this it requires an ubuntu password which i dont have because i use vs code inside the company's server, my pc uses windows 11 but this virtual machine uses ubuntu... so i tried to forcelly change react native version to 0.64.4 and now the log error is not even showing in the app anymore, app is not building.
It says  ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
probably because of the forced change but I dont know I just dont want to be kicked off in 1 week of my first project for an international client
I tried to npx react-native run-ios and run-android, i tried to install brew, pod, cocoapods, all of them required sudo command which requires a password which i dont and cannot have access.. My tech lead could not help me, the pm just wants the tasks to be done.. the other rn dev of the team couldnt help... so im asking you guys
